# Using the_posts_pagination with offset adds extra empty page

Tags: pagination

I'm working on a quite complex query, it has a different post count on the first page and on paginated pages, to achieve that I'm using offset and this seem to mess up the_posts_pagination.

Here's the code:

**index.php**

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 //post content here...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php
    the_posts_pagination( array(
        'mid_size'  => 2,
        'prev_text' => __( 'Prev', 'textdomain' ),
        'next_text' => __( 'Next', 'textdomain' ),
    ));
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
function my_offset( $query ) {
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    $first_page_ppp = 3;
    $paged = $query->query_vars[ 'paged' ];

    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( !is_paged() ) {

            $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $first_page_ppp );

        } else {
            $paged_offset = $first_page_ppp + ( ($paged - 2) * $ppp );
            $query->set( 'offset', $paged_offset );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_offset' );

function my_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    $first_page_ppp = 3;

    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( !is_paged() ) {

            return( $found_posts );

        } else {

            return( $found_posts - ($first_page_ppp - $ppp) );

        }
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'my_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
```

The post per page is set to 5 in the reading settings, but the issue is there no matter what it's set to.

Now using this code the the_posts_pagination will show at least one extra empty page in the numbered pagination links. However if I go to the second page then the numbered pagination will display the correct number of max pages.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: The problem is `max_num_pages` in inaccurate, but there's no filter for that. It's calculated with `found_posts / posts_per_page`, so I think your only option is to adjust what `found_posts` filter returns on the first page to make `max_num_pages` what it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you! So I believe I got something working. Instead of using the_post_pagination I switched to paginate_links, this lets me set the total number of pages. Then I basically did like this:

$amount = $wp_query->found_posts;
$totalpages = $amount - (3 - 5);
   
echo paginate_links( array(
 .....
 'total' => $totalpages / 5
) );


3 is posts per page on the first page and 5 is on paginated pages.
Does this seem like a crazy solution?

Comment: I updated the post so you can see the code more easily

Comment: Glad you got it working! You can add your solution as an answer and the system will let you accept it after a short wait period.

Comment: @sebfck can you post your answer as an answer instead of editing it into your question? Nobody can upvote it if you don't, and your can't mark it as the answer unless you post it

Comment: Moved the edit to an answer, looks like I have to wait 2 days before I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Milo I found something that's making it work as expected:

Changes made to index.php :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
 //post content here...
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php
global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer
$amount = $wp_query->found_posts;
$totalpages = $amount - (3 - 5);

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $totalpages / 5
) );
?>
```

So I switched over to paginate_links which lets me set a total number of pages which I could calculate using the found_posts and 3(amount of posts on first page) and 5(amount of posts on paginated pages).

**EDIT:**

Found another better solution:

```
function my_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
    $first_page_ppp = 3;

    if( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if( !is_paged() ) {

            return( $first_page_ppp + ( $found_posts - $first_page_ppp ) * $first_page_ppp / $ppp );

        } else {

            return( $found_posts - ($first_page_ppp - $ppp) );

        }
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
add_filter( 'found_posts', 'my_offset_pagination', 10, 2 );
```